# Good way in clojure to map function on multiple items of coll or seqence

Tags: clojure

I'm currently learning Clojure, and I'm trying to learn how to do things the best way. Today I'm looking at the basic concept of doing things on a sequence, I know the basics of map, filter and reduce. Now I want to try to do a thing to pairs of elements in a sequence, and I found two ways of doing it. The function I apply is println. The output is simply 12 34 56 7

```
(def xs [1 2 3 4 5 6 7])
(defn work_on_pairs [xs]
  (loop [data xs]
    (if (empty? data)
      data
      (do
        (println (str (first data) (second data)))
       (recur (drop 2 data))))))
(work_on_pairs xs)
```

I mean, I could do like this

```
(map println (zipmap (take-nth 2 xs) (take-nth 2 (drop 1 xs))))
;; prints [1 2] [3 4] [5 6], and we loose the last element because zip.
```

But it is not really nice.. My background is in Python, where I could just say `zip(xs[::2], xs[1::2])` But I guess this is not the Clojure way to do it. 
So I'm looking for suggestions on how to do this same thing, in the best Clojure way.

I realize I'm so new to Clojure I don't even know what this kind of operation is called.

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with [`partition-all`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition-all):

```
(def xs [1 2 3 4 5 6 7])

(->> xs
     (partition-all 2)  ; Gives ((1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (7))
     (map (partial apply str))  ; or use (map #(apply str %))
     (apply println))

12 34 56 7
```

The `map` line is just to join the pairs so the "()" don't end up in the output.

If you want each pair printed on its own line, change `(apply println)` to `(run! println)`. Your expected output seems to disagree with your code, so that's unclear.

Comment: I'd prefer to use `partition-all` than to use `partition` with an empty padding collection.

Comment: @amalloy Wow, I'm not sure how I managed to never notice that function before. Just a sec, I'll edit. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: In #clojure, there's a bot that, among other things, can be taught factoids. It has for years, I think at least since 2011, mapped the string `partition` to "`partition` is probably not what you want; see `partition-all`".

Comment: @amalloy Oh. Maybe when I come back to writing Clojure again I'll reconsider my previous usages of `partition`. I see that `partition-all` doesn't have the same weird behavior that `partition` has when passed a non-integer `n` (it returns an empty collection). That's bit me a few times. `partition-all` seems to round `n` up, which makes more sense.

Comment: Nice!. I did not know of `partition-all` or `run!` before. I guess the ! in `run!` is for hinting at side-effects. Also I got surprised by the `apply println` term. I was convinced that println returns `nil`, so this still confuses me.

Comment: @user55924 Yes, in general, `!` indicates that a function is used to carry out side effects. You could also use `mapv` here instead of `run!`, but conceptually that isn't as good of a fit since the purpose of `mapv` is to return a transformed collection. And `println` *does* return `nil`. `(apply println [1 2 3])` is the same as `(println 1 2 3)`. `apply` is used to apply a list of arguments to a function.

Comment: @user55924 `(apply println ["12" "34" "56" "7"])` (what you'll get with my above code) is the same as `(println "12" "34" "56" "7")` I'm using `apply` so the collection returned by `map` can be applied directly to `println`. Play around with it for a bit.

Comment: @user55924 Actually, since you're from a Python background, `(apply println [1 2 3])` would, in Python be: `print(*[1, 2, 3])`. `apply` is Clojure's "spread operator".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to dip into transducers, you can do something similar to the threading (`->>`) form of the accepted answer, but in a single pass over the data.

Assuming

```
(def xs [1 2 3 4 5 6 7])
```

has been evaluated already,

```
(transduce
  (comp
    (partition-all 2)
    (map #(apply str %)))

  conj
  []

  xs)
```

should give you the same output if you wrap it in

```
(apply println ...)
```

We supply `conj` (reducing fn) and `[]` (initial data structure) to specify how the `reduce` process inside `transduce` should build up the result.

I wouldn't use a transducer for a list that small, or a process that simple, but it's good to know what's possible!

Comment: I was waiting for the transducer option, just been reading about it. :) Eventually I was going to add it myself. I would like to add that the main point of the transducer solution is that transducers are composable, so this could be composed into a larger processing function.
It is also nice to have a macro-less option.